# Swagger POST/PUT body parameters not passing to my controller

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui

My simple swagger API documentation. parameters not passing to my controller while performing post and put operations.(Get and Delete operations performs fine)

Swaggerjson file:

```
"paths": {       
    "/api/AddEmployee": {
        "post": {
            "summary": "Add an Employee",
            "description": "Adds a new Employee to the employees list.",
            "consumes": [
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "body",
                    "in": "body",
                    "required": true,
                    "description": "An Employee to create.",
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Employee"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "Employee Added Sucessfully"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "/api/UpdateEmployee": {
        "post": {
            "summary": "Update an Employee",
            "description": "Updates an exist employee",
            "consumes": [
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "body",
                    "in": "body",
                    "description": "An Employee to be updated.",
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Employees"
                    }

                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "Employee Added Sucessfully"
                }
            }
        }
    }

},
"definitions": {
    "Employees": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "EmpId": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
            },
            "FirstName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "LastName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "age": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    },
    "Employee": {
        "Type": "object",
        "required": [
            "FirstName",
            "LastName",
            "age"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "FirstName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "LastName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "age": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
  }
```

}

Could any one guide on this issue. TIA !

[image: Controller Add and Update]

[image: Error Msg]

Comment: I guess your using WebApi? If so, can you post your controller, action and routes details you expect to receive the request? The problem is likely to be there.

Comment: @PhilCooper Updated, Could you check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blunder:

"consumes": [
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ],

Change to:

"consumes": [
                "application/json"
            ],